# importing pictures from iphone to PC

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

Does anyone know anyway to make the iTunes sync photos taken using camera on my phone  into my PC?

I've enabled the iTunes photo sync already but it isn't working.

Right now I'm accessing the photos in the My Computer and right click Import Pictures (or Explore) .

Comment: To my knowledge, that's the way you're meant to do it.  Photo Syncing is for getting photos onto the iPhone.

Comment: It is possible, you can select a folder of selection of folders to sync on a PC in the absence of (obviously) iPhoto, or any other photo management software.  The OP needs to describe exactly how s/he has set it up and define what "doesn't work" means for us to help more.

Comment: i don't have a mac. i'm using windows vista